# How do i select the value of a certain column from the last row in sqlite3 and python?

Tags: python, sqlite

At the moment i do not have set `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` as i do not need it but i will if it is the easiest way.

So i set up my database and table:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('lista.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unu(echipa1 TEXT UNIQUE, scor1 TEXT, scor2 TEXT, echipa2 TEXT, '
      'cota FLOAT, miza INT, stare INT)')
```

i insert some values

```
c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO unu( echipa1,scor1, scor2, echipa2, cota, miza, stare  ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                                                                          (echipa1, scor1, scor2, echipa2, cota, miza, stare))
```

so how do i select the value for `stare` from the last row?

```
c.execute("SELECT stare FROM  unu WHERE id = Max")
```

So i know i do not have an id, but does sqlite count the rows even if i do not assign a id to each row?
If not i will set a `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`

```
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unu(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, echipa1 TEXT UNIQUE, scor1 TEXT, scor2 TEXT, echipa2 TEXT, '
      'cota FLOAT, miza INT, stare INT)')
```

Will then my select query work?

Comment: I'd recommend getting an sql explorer such as sequel pro and running the queries manually before converting to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your definition of last row. If you want to select the row you just inserted, you can use `cursor.lastrowid`.

```
c.execute("SELECT stare FROM unu WHERE ROWID=(?)", (c.lastrowid,))
```

If you want the last row anyone inserted (someone may have inserted a row between the insert and select statements), then you need a PK with AUTOINCREMENT (just "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" will make it a copy of the ROWID which is not guaranteed to be in crescent order):

```
c.execute("SELECT stare FROM unu ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
```

Comment: I guess in Sqlite you can get away without a primary key if you replace `id` with `ROWID` (untested). But a surrogate primary key does not hurt and make for more portable, explicit code.

Comment: The second part is not true/guaranteed because unless you use AUTOINCREMENT when declaring the primary key SQLite does not guarantee that ROWID/the primary key uses strictly increasing values but may also fill ”holes” from deleted rows or rolled back transactions. So the ROWID of the latest inserted row doesn't have to be the biggest one in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You don't just need to declare the `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column but also make it `AUTOINCREMENT` to really guarantee the latest inserted row also has the largest `ROWID`/primary key value.  Otherwise SQLite may fill ”holes” left by deleted rows or failed/rolled back transactions.